# Mongodb connection fails when selecting or inserting with java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using `mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar` and also tried with `mongo-2.10.1.jar` both are giving the following error.The database is
connected but the collection insert and selection are not working.

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;

public class mongo_test {
    public MongoClient mongo = null;
    public DB mongodb = null;

    private void mongo_startconnection() {
        try {
            mongo = new MongoClient("10.0.2.15", 27017);
            mongodb = mongo.getDB("foobar");
            System.out.println("Mongodb is connected");
            BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
            DBCollection collection = mongodb.getCollection("url_ta");
            Set<String> colls = mongodb.getCollectionNames();
            for (String s : colls) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MongoException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        mongo_test MT = new mongo_test();
        MT.mongo_startconnection();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Mongodb is connected
Nov 26, 2013 11:34:39 AM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection
WARNING: Exception executing isMaster command on /10.0.2.15:27017
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:223)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:125)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:106)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:162)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:547)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:526)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:236)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
    at com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:400)
    at mongo_test.mongo_startconnection(mongo_test.java:29)
    at mongo_test.main(mongo_test.java:69)
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /10.0.2.15:27017 failed on database foobar at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:253)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
    at com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:400)
    at mongo_test.mongo_startconnection(mongo_test.java:29)
    at mongo_test.main(mongo_test.java:69)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:223)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:125)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:244)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Can you try connecting to the mongo server using the mongo shell command on the same machine that you are running the application? I think you might have network issues that are preventing connection to it.

Comment: The mongo server is connected up and running but if I try to work on collections then I'm getting the above error

Comment: If that is the case, do you have multiple multiple MongoDB servers in a replicaSet configuration? Are you connecting to a slave server?

Answer (score 2):

1.Trying to find out whether your ip address and port number is reachable.
use command: `telnet 10.0.2.15",27017` to check if such a port for this ip is open for connection.

2.If you have the authority to login the mongodb server ,just login and then:

- If your mongodb is a cluster , Use commmand : `ps -ef|grep mongos` to check the mongodb server instance is up and the port is just
  27017.

  if your mongodb is just a single machine ,use `ps -ef|grep mongod` to make the same check.

Comment: Thanks Vico,I have checked the both commands and mongodb is up,but when I try work with collections then I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Well ,I download you code and run it on my own machine , it works just fine.Driver version I use is  2.10.1.Just download it here:https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/downloads

Comment: Very helpful, @Vico_Wu! This could be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
package raamji.com.start;

//import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        //crete Connection
        Mongo mongoClient = new Mongo("ind-asingh", 27017);//or "localhost",27017
        System.out.println("mongoClient :" + mongoClient);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("DB Name");//e.g. MYDB
        System.out.println("db :" + db);

//---------------------------Access your Collection-----------------------------
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("message");
        System.out.println("collection :" + collection);
        System.out.println("Message Count: " + collection.getCount());

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }


    }//end pf psvm

}//end of class
```